# Handling Groups in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a game where when you kill an enemy, two more will take its place. The idea is you will not be able to beat it, due to the infinite number of mobs. My problem is getting spawning of the new mobs. Also, whenever I hit a the old mobs position, it re-appears and resumes chasing the player, and cannot be killed. Here is what I have so far:

[Mob Class]

```
class MOB(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.pos = [0,0]
        self.image = ENEMY
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = location
        self.speed = random
        self.hp = 4
    def update(self):
        if self.rect.centerx >= Player.rect.centerx:
            self.rect.left = self.rect.left - 4
        if self.rect.centerx <= Player.rect.centerx:
            self.rect.left = self.rect.left + 4
        if self.rect.centery <= Player.rect.centery:
            self.rect.top = self.rect.top + 4
        if self.rect.centery >= Player.rect.centery:
            self.rect.top = self.rect.top - 4
```

[Shooting a mob]

```
for Mob in mobs:
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(Bullet, Mob) == True:
        mobs.remove(Mob)
        Bullet.image = NOBULLET
        Mob.hp = Mob.hp - 2
```

[Killing a mob]

```
for Mob in mobs:
    if Mob.hp == 0:
        mobs.remove(Mob)
            new_mobs = MOB([50,50]), MOB([51, 300]) 
            mobs.add(new_mobs)
```

[Updating Screen]

```
mobs.update()
mobs.draw(screen)
```

Comment: That is also my question @Wooble, but without enough code, can you help me at all?

Comment: "My problem is getting spawning of the new mobs" -- and what is the problem with that? Also "Also, whenever I hit a the old mobs position, it re-appears and resumes chasing the player, and cannot be killed" -- is that what you want or is that what is happening?

Comment: @martineau 1) Only one of them appears and chases the player. I need it so both of them appear and chase the player. 2) That is whats happening. I don't want that.

Comment: OK, that helps, thanks. 1) You don't show the class of the `mobs` variable, which is likely causing the problems. For instance, is `mobs.add()` adding all the Mob's it's passed to where ever they are stored? If so, why isn't `mobs.update()` finding and displaying them? 2) Similarly, it doesn't sound like `mobs.remove()` is performing the all the needed actions to truly get rid of the mob that was killed (other making them disappear, but only temporarily). BTW, what does the `hp` attribute of a `Mob` object represent?

Comment: If the mob appears when the player goes over its position, perhaps you should show what the player's code does.